# how to set svg picture as background of container in flutter?

Tags: css, flutter, svg, background, containers

I cannot figure out how to set background image of container using svg picture !
I tried setting image as background but it didnt work
that method works with asset images or online images but is not successfully working with svg pictures
i am using svg.picture .
I am noobie !

Comment: The argument type 'PictureProvider<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>getting this error on this code : decoration: BoxDecoration(
   image: DecorationImage(
 image: SvgPicture.asset(
 'assets/images/background.svg',
                                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                ).pictureProvider!,
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              ),
                                            ),

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_svg_provider/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package to display the svg image.

Instead of using it as background image, i suggest you to use `Stack` to stack the svg image in the back and your widget in the front.

Example

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/background.svg',
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
        ),
        Container(
          child:  << Your Widget >>,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SVG as `Container's child` or If you need just for background then use `Stack`:

```
Column(
        children: [

          //with Stack
          Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              SvgPicture.network("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Bananas.svg",),
              Container(
                height: 200,width: 200,
                color: Colors.yellow.shade200,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text("Hello! World"),
              )
            ],
          ),

          //with Container
          Container(
            height: 250,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              color: Colors.yellow.shade200,
            ),
            child: SvgPicture.network("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Bananas.svg",),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use an SVG as the background of a container in Flutter, you can use the `DecoratedBox` along with the `SvgPicture.asset` widget.

Here is an example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/background.svg',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ).pictureProvider.toImage(100,100), //Example sizes
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hello, world!',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 32.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I haven't test it, I'm not sure if it works. If you get any error just tell me!

Comment: The argument type 'PictureProvider<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'.

Comment: I've updated my code, give it a try

Comment: `The getter 'pictureProvider' isn't defined for the type 'SvgPicture'.` got this error. is there any extension I have to add?

Answer (score 0):

**I'm trying to Solve your Problem:**

**Code:**

```
 Container(
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           image: DecorationImage(
             image: SvgPicture.asset(
               'assets/images/background.svg',
               fit: BoxFit.cover,
             ).pictureProvider,
             fit: BoxFit.cover,
           ),
         ),
         child: Text("");
       );
```

Comment: The argument type 'PictureProvider<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `svg_provider` package for the same. You might have to set flutter_svg version to ^1.0.1 to make it work.

```dart
return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: svg_provider.Svg(svgPath),
            fit: BoxFit.none),
      ),
    );
```